# Single upload file attribute in an entity Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an user entity that I´d wish to add an upload image variable and an upload file variable.

I wonder if there is a way to implement that without create another two extra bundles for Documents and Images like [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) suggests.

Is [this tutorial](http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/230/snippet-for-quick-single-file-upload-in-symfony-2-0/) totally correct? Lifecycle Callbacks shouldn´t be there?

EDIT: **My question is**: What variables and methods should I add to my entity if I´d want to have (upload) file and image variables into it?

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not that clear. Still Yes you can do that with one single entity and can upload different file types without the need of extra bundle. This can be carried out in your form type effectively.

Comment: How I can do that? Adding all attributes and methods of Document bundle example of [the cookbook] (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) to my custom bundle?